# How to save Rally Time Entry value for other user through API TimeEntryValue?

Tags: api, integration, rally

In RALLY we have seen that One can login through API and can fill Time entry for there own.Can with API one user can fill the time value for other user.

if I do the time sheet  integration between Rally and any other Tool Ideally this is not possible to store all user credential and fill the time sheet for all users through Rally API.

Please suggest if any way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deb

Answer (score 0):

User A cannot set TimeEntryValues for user B, even if user A is a subscription admin. It is not supported in the UI, and it is not supported in WS API.